# batch script to copy a set of lines from the text file and paste the values in another text file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting. I need to get an output as below. please help me in getting that.

## The master file contains the below lines but i need the output only as Ids. we can omit other lines

```
Vendor daemon status (on W1PVAP1059):



 ibmratl: UP v11.10
Feature usage info:

Users of ClearQuest:  (Total of 378 licenses issued;  Total of 48 licenses in use)

  "`ClearQuest`" `v1.10000`, 

vendor: rational
  floating license

F19H3BD 0 W1PVAP1059 F19H3BD_cq_win_3_0 (v1.1) (W1PVAP1059/27000 4486), start Sun 1/18 23:28
F1VQXIG 0 W1PVAP1059 F1VQXIG_cq_win_92_0 (v1.1) (W1PVAP1059/27000 891), start Sun 1/18 23:59
F28XJV0 0 W1PVAP1059 F28XJV0_cq_win_29_0 (v1.1) (W1PVAP1059/27000 4981), start Sun 1/18 23:45
F2HGGK7 0 W1PVAP1059 F2HGGK7_cq_win_27_0 (v1.1) (W1PVAP1059/27000 2951), start Sun 1/18 23:44
F2MIHSF 0 W1PVAP1059 F2MIHSF_cq_win_15_0 (v1.1) (W1PVAP1059/27000 3649), start Sun 1/18 23:35
F2S2WHP 0 W1PVAP1059 F2S2WHP_cq_win_24_0 (v1.1) (W1PVAP1059/27000 3137), start Sun 1/18 23:41..
===============================================================
```

I would like to get the output values as below(only the IDS)

```
F19H3BD
F1VQXIG
F28XJV0
F2HGGK7
F2MIHSF
F2S2WHP
```

Also please let me know if you need any additional information

Comment: Is the data you require in column 1 or column 4? Is the indenting of the last data line a typo or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1,4delims=_ " %%a IN (q28022229.txt) DO (
  IF "%%a"=="%%b" ECHO(%%a
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28022229.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set "ids_file=c:\ids.txt"
set "new_file=c:\ids2.txt"

for /f "tokens=1" %%a  in ('type "%ids_file%"^|find /i " (v1.1) "') do (
    (echo(%%a)
)>>"%new_file%"
```

Comment: I think ot would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: @reporter - in fact the solution is pretty straightforward.Just types the file with `TYPE`, filter the result with `FIND` and `FOR /F` separates output on tokens.